# Ingress-controller forcing SSL on port 80 (HTTP)

Tags: azure, ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm running a node.js application in Kubernetes and I'm using an ingress controller to use SSL on port 443. It's working, however it is forcing me to use SSL on port 80 as well which I don't want.

I've tried adding nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false" to my ingress but it still forces SSL on port 80. This is what the ingress config looks like:

```
{
  "kind": "Ingress",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "http-rest-api-ingress",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/http-rest-api-ingress",
    "uid": "f89ad4cd-9d9d-11e9-9d4d-1aa06e634f15",
    "resourceVersion": "1990981",
    "generation": 2,
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-07-03T14:22:21Z",
    "annotations": {
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target": "/$1",
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect": "false"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "host": "x.x.com",
        "http": {
          "paths": [
            {
              "backend": {
                "path": "/(.*)",
                "serviceName": "http-rest-api",
                "servicePort": 4500
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {
      "ingress": [
        {}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it should be it according to the docs: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect. what do you see in the ingress logs?

Comment: Are you using a browser to test? If so, is it possible this is a caching issue in the browser? Try clearing the cache and/or using curl to verify.

Comment: How are you testing? Where is Kubernetes running? Is there another LoadBalancer service in front of the Ingress? Please update the question with this and other comments requested information. Post commands used to test, `describe` output of relevant resources, and the manifests.